# LLVM JIT tutorial code crashes with simple parameterized function. Why?

Tags: c++, assembly, llvm, jit

I'm trying to learn my way around the LLVM infrastructure. I've installed the LLVM binaries for Windows on a MinGW installation.

I'm following the tutorial found on the LLVM site about the so-called Kaleidoscope language. I have a source file that has *exactly* the code listing **[at the end of this page](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl4.html)**.

Also, if it's of any importance, I'm building using the following flags (obtained through `llvm-config` ahead of time, because the Windows shell doesn't have very comfortable substitution syntax):

`clang++ -g -O3 kaleido.cpp -o kaleido.exe -IC:/MinGW/include  -DNDEBUG -D__NO_CTYPE_INLINE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -LC:/MinGW/lib  -lLLVMCore  -lLLVMSupport -lpthread -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMJIT -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -lm -limagehlp -lpsapi`

Using that proposed language implemented in the linked code, I'm testing a few top level expressions. First, one with literals:

```
ready> 5 + 3;
ready> Read top-level expression:
define double @0() {
entry:
  ret double 8.000000e+00
}

Evaluated to 8.000000
```

...Works as expected. Then a function definition with a constant result:

```
ready> def f(x) 12;
ready> Read function definition:
define double @f(double %x) {
entry:
  ret double 1.200000e+01
}
```

...Again, working as expected. Calling this for any input gives a fixed result:

```
ready> f(5);
ready> Read top-level expression:
define double @1() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call double @f(double 5.000000e+00)
  ret double %calltmp
}

Evaluated to 12.000000
```

...No surprise. Then, a function definition that does something with the parameter:

```
ready> def g(x) x + 1;
ready> Read function definition:
define double @g(double %x) {
entry:
  %addtmp = fadd double 1.000000e+00, %x
  ret double %addtmp
}
```

...Looks like it's okay, the bytecode is generated. Now, calling it:

```
ready> g(5);
ready> Read top-level expression:
define double @2() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call double @g(double 5.000000e+00)
  ret double %calltmp
}

0x00D400A4 (0x0000000A 0x00000000 0x0028FF28 0x00D40087) <unknown module>
0x00C7A5E0 (0x01078A28 0x010CF040 0x0028FEF0 0x40280000)
0x004023F1 (0x00000001 0x01072FD0 0x01071B10 0xFFFFFFFF)
0x004010B9 (0x00000001 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000)
0x00401284 (0x7EFDE000 0x0028FFD4 0x77E59F42 0x7EFDE000)
0x75693677 (0x7EFDE000 0x7B3361A2 0x00000000 0x00000000), BaseThreadInitThunk() + 0x12 bytes(s)
0x77E59F42 (0x0040126C 0x7EFDE000 0x00000000 0x00000000), RtlInitializeExceptionChain() + 0x63 bytes(s)
0x77E59F15 (0x0040126C 0x7EFDE000 0x00000000 0x78746341), RtlInitializeExceptionChain() + 0x36 bytes(s)
```

...Crashes.

Through some rudimentary debugging, I've come to believe that the involved pieces of code, meaning the one for the top-level expression (the call to `g(x)` with an argument of 5) and for the one for the called function, are both JIT-compiled successfully. I believe this is the case because I get the function pointer *before* the crash (and I'm assuming the execution engine returns a function pointer only *after* it has successfully compiled the function). To be more precise, the crash happens exactly at the point where the function pointer is run, meaning this line in my source file (in `HandleTopLevelExpression()`):

```
  fprintf(stderr, "Evaluated to %f\n", FP());
```

Most probably the line itself is innocent, because it runs successfully for other functions. The culprit is likely somewhere inside the function pointed by `FP` in the last of the above examples, but since that code is runtime generated, I don't have it in my `cpp` file.

**Any ideas on why it might be crashing on that specific scenario?**

---

**UPDATE #1:** Running the process through gdb shows this at the crash point:

> Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.

And a trace that doesn't tell me anything:

```
0x00ee0044 in ?? ()
```

---

**UPDATE #2:** In an attempt to shed some more light on this, here's the assembly around the crash:

```
00D70068   55               PUSH EBP
00D70069   89E5             MOV EBP,ESP
00D7006B   81E4 F8FFFFFF    AND ESP,FFFFFFF8
00D70071   83EC 08          SUB ESP,8
00D70074   C5FB             LDS EDI,EBX     ; Here!                  ; Illegal use of register
00D70076   1045 08          ADC BYTE PTR SS:[EBP+8],AL
00D70079   C5FB             LDS EDI,EBX                              ; Illegal use of register
00D7007B   58               POP EAX
00D7007C   05 6000D700      ADD EAX,0D70060
00D70081   C5FB             LDS EDI,EBX                              ; Illegal use of register
00D70083   110424           ADC DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],EAX
00D70086   DD0424           FLD QWORD PTR SS:[ESP]
00D70089   89EC             MOV ESP,EBP
00D7008B   5D               POP EBP
00D7008C   C3               RETN
```

The crash is happening at `00D70074`, the instruction being `LDS EDI,EBX`. It is a few addresses higher than the address pointed by `FP` (which makes me believe that this all might be JIT-emitted code, but please take this conclusion with a grain of salt, as I'm over my head here).

As you can see, the disassembler has also placed a comment on that and the next similar lines, saying it's an illegal use of the register. To be honest, I don't know *why* this specific extended register pair is illegal for this instruction, but **if it is illegal, why is it there at all and how can we make the compiler produce legal code?**

Comment: If you are comfortable with with assembly language debugging, it would be a good place to start.  Step into FP().

Comment: Regarding your edits - a SIGILL after a function call via a pointer indicates that the pointer is not pointing to valid machine code. Debugging it or tracing into it won't help in that case. To be sure, you can dump the content of the FP pointer (and a few bytes after it) to verify whether there really is valid machine code there.

Comment: @Oak This is what came to my mind too. I've printed the hex values of two similar functions (one that works and one that crashes), in numbers of 32-bits. The outputs look relatively similar - the point being, the area around the "bad" function pointer certainly does *not* look like garbage. Should I try to map them to opcodes? Also, why would the JIT compile invalid code? Could it be a bug in my LLVM binaries?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I think it's worth mapping them to opcode and checking what's going on. A usual JIT failure should return NULL, not garbage, so something's fishy here. As for "why" would it compile invalid code - I'm afraid don't know, this is why I only wrote a comment and not an answer :( my guess is that the code is valid, but something in the calling convention is off and it only manifests when the called function tries to use an argument. But this is just a guess.

Comment: @Oak I've included the assembly around the address that causes the `SIGILL`. (It's all still for the scenario I described above.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently LLVM is generating VEX-prefixed AVX instructions for you, but your processor doesn't support that instruction set (and neither does your disassembler).

AVX-aware decoding of your JIT bytes give the following valid code:

```
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   81 e4 f8 ff ff ff       and    esp,0xfffffff8
   9:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
   c:   c5 fb 10 45 08          vmovsd xmm0,QWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
  11:   c5 fb 58 05 60 00 d7    vaddsd xmm0,xmm0,QWORD PTR ds:0xd70060
  18:   00
  19:   c5 fb 11 04 24          vmovsd QWORD PTR [esp],xmm0
  1e:   dd 04 24                fld    QWORD PTR [esp]
  21:   89 ec                   mov    esp,ebp
  23:   5d                      pop    ebp
  24:   c3                      ret
```

If LLVM is misdetecting your native architecture, or if you just want to override it, you can change the `EngineBuilder` used in the sample code, for example like:

```cpp
TheExecutionEngine = EngineBuilder(TheModule).setErrorStr(&ErrStr).setMCPU("i386").create();
```

You can also set the architecture or provide attributes.